# get_terms() does not return all term fields

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using wordpress toolset for creting term fileds.

I have created taxonomie called clients and
I have created Term filed called "client-logo-image" with a group name of "client logo"

When I call get_terms() and dump the var everything is there except "client-logo-image", for example "slug" and "description" are there.

This is my code:

```
    $terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'client',
    'hide_empty' => false,
) );
```

plugin I'm using https://toolset.com/

Any help I will appreciate even changing the plugin or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

```
$term = get_queried_object();
$terms = get_term($term, 'client' );
$terms_cat = array('hide_empty' => false);
```

Comment: Hi man, thank you. But I'm not sure how I would use this. Can you expand your answer a little bit more?